# Is there a slice equivalent to "append" in Python?

Tags: python

To prepend to a list, I use the_list[0:0]. But with slice appending:

- [-0:-0] doesn't work.
- [::-1][0:0] doesn't work.
- And obviously [-1:-1] won't work.
- [len(the_list), len(the_list)] doesn't count -- looking for just numbers here

Example:

```
results = [3,1,0]
results[-1:-1] = [3]
print(results)

>>> [3,1,3,0]

results[-0:-0] = 5
print(results)

>>> [5,3,1,3,0]

results = [3,1,0]
results[-1:-1] = [3]
print(results)

>>> [3,1,3,0]

results[-0:-0] = 5
print(results)

>>> [5,3,1,3,0]
```

Thoughts?

Comment: How are you able to prepend in the first place? Which python are you using?

Comment: No methods. Just a  [0:0] slice operator. (the_list[0:0])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slice that starts after the last element is `len(…):`.

```
results[len(results):] = [3]
```

but why, when there are `+=` and `extend`?

```
results += [3]
results.extend([3])
```

Comment: True. I was trying to go without using len(). Will edit my question for that. += works. And by inference, I'll say there's no slice operator for appending.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#typesseq-mutable).  This can be used to add the members of one list to the end of another.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]

l1.extend(l2)    # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```